# Generalized NumPy reshape function to imitate einsum syntax

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I often perform a lot of `reshape()`, `transpose()` or `squeeze()` operations on `numpy` arrays for numeric calculations. Often, this obfuscates the code. The initial shape as well as the resulting shape is unknown.

**Prior solutions involved:**

- Comments (which may outdate).
- Tiny functions with somewhat helpful names `from_tbf_to_f1tb()`.

Since experiments change quickly, so do the dimensions. I always enjoy using [`numpy.einsum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), so I wanted a syntax similar to that, but just for reshapes.

**Example:**

`reshape(A, 't b f -> f 1 b*t')`

The test case shows further examples.

How can I simplify my code and make it more readable?

```
import sys
import unittest
import numpy as np
import nt.testing as tc
from nt.utils.numpy_utils import reshape


def _normalize(op):
    op = op.replace(',', '')
    op = op.replace(' ', '')
    op = ' '.join(c for c in op)
    op = op.replace(' * ', '*')
    op = op.replace('- >', '->')
    return op


def _only_reshape(array, source, target):
    source, target = source.split(), target.replace(' * ', '*').split()
    input_shape = {key: array.shape[index] for index, key in enumerate(source)}

    output_shape = []
    for t in target:
        product = 1
        if not t == '1':
            t = t.split('*')
            for t_ in t:
                product *= input_shape[t_]
        output_shape.append(product)

    return array.reshape(output_shape)


def reshape(array, operation):
    """ This is an experimental version of a generalized reshape.

    See test cases for examples.
    """
    operation = _normalize(operation)

    if '*' in operation.split('->')[0]:
        raise NotImplementedError(
            'Unflatten operation not supported by design. '
            'Actual values for dimensions are not available to this function.'
        )

    # Initial squeeze
    squeeze_operation = operation.split('->')[0].split()
    for axis, op in reversed(list(enumerate(squeeze_operation))):
        if op == '1':
            array = np.squeeze(array, axis=axis)

    # Transpose
    transposition_operation = operation.replace('1', ' ').replace('*', ' ')
    try:
        array = np.einsum(transposition_operation, array)
    except ValueError as e:
        msg = 'op: {}, shape: {}'.format(transposition_operation,
                                         np.shape(array))
        if len(e.args) == 1:
            e.args = (e.args[0]+'\n\n'+msg,)
        else:
            print(msg)
        raise

    # Final reshape
    source = transposition_operation.split('->')[-1]
    target = operation.split('->')[-1]

    return _only_reshape(array, source, target)
```

**Testcase:**

```
T, B, F = 40, 6, 51
A = np.random.uniform(size=(T, B, F))
A2 = np.random.uniform(size=(T, 1, B, F))
A3 = np.random.uniform(size=(T*B*F,))
A4 = np.random.uniform(size=(T, 1, 1, B, 1, F))


class TestReshape(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_noop_comma(self):
        result = reshape(A, 'T,B,F->T,B,F')
        tc.assert_equal(result.shape, (T, B, F))
        tc.assert_equal(result, A)

    def test_noop_space(self):
        result = reshape(A, 'T B F->T B F')
        tc.assert_equal(result.shape, (T, B, F))
        tc.assert_equal(result, A)

    def test_noop_mixed(self):
        result = reshape(A, 'tbf->t, b f')
        tc.assert_equal(result.shape, (T, B, F))
        tc.assert_equal(result, A)

    def test_transpose_comma(self):
        result = reshape(A, 'T,B,F->F,T,B')
        tc.assert_equal(result.shape, (F, T, B))
        tc.assert_equal(result, A.transpose(2, 0, 1))

    def test_transpose_mixed(self):
        result = reshape(A, 't, b, f -> f t b')
        tc.assert_equal(result.shape, (F, T, B))
        tc.assert_equal(result, A.transpose(2, 0, 1))

    def test_broadcast_axis_0(self):
        result = reshape(A, 'T,B,F->1,T,B,F')
        tc.assert_equal(result.shape, (1, T, B, F))
        tc.assert_equal(result, A[None, ...])

    def test_broadcast_axis_2(self):
        result = reshape(A, 'T,B,F->T,B,1,F')
        tc.assert_equal(result.shape, (T, B, 1, F))
        tc.assert_equal(result, A[..., None, :])

    def test_broadcast_axis_3(self):
        result = reshape(A, 'T,B,F->T,B,F,1')
        tc.assert_equal(result.shape, (T, B, F, 1))
        tc.assert_equal(result, A[..., None])

    def test_reshape_comma(self):
        result = reshape(A, 'T,B,F->T,B*F')
        tc.assert_equal(result.shape, (T, B*F))
        tc.assert_equal(result, A.reshape(T, B*F))

    def test_reshape_comma_unflatten(self):
        with tc.assert_raises(NotImplementedError):
            reshape(A3, 't*b*f->t, b, f')

    def test_reshape_comma_unflatten_and_transpose_and_flatten(self):
        with tc.assert_raises(NotImplementedError):
            reshape(A3, 't*b*f->f, t*b')

    def test_reshape_comma_flat(self):
        result = reshape(A, 'T,B,F->T*B*F')
        tc.assert_equal(result.shape, (T*B*F,))
        tc.assert_equal(result, A.ravel())

    def test_reshape_comma_with_singleton_input(self):
        result = reshape(A2, 'T, 1, B, F -> T*B*F')
        tc.assert_equal(result.shape, (T*B*F,))
        tc.assert_equal(result, A2.ravel())

    def test_reshape_comma_with_a_lot_of_singleton_inputs(self):
        result = reshape(A4, 'T, 1, 1, B, 1, F -> T*B*F')
        tc.assert_equal(result.shape, (T*B*F,))
        tc.assert_equal(result, A4.ravel())

    def test_reshape_and_broadcast(self):
        tc.assert_equal(reshape(A, 'T,B,F->T,1,B*F').shape, (T, 1, B*F))
        tc.assert_equal(reshape(A, 'T,B,F->T,1,B*F').ravel(), A.ravel())

    def test_reshape_and_broadcast_many(self):
        result = reshape(A, 'T,B,F->1,T,1,B*F,1')
        tc.assert_equal(result.shape, (1, T, 1, B*F, 1))

    def test_swap_and_reshape(self):
        result = reshape(A, 'T,B,F->T,F*B')
        tc.assert_equal(result.shape, (T, F * B))
        tc.assert_equal(result, A.swapaxes(-1, -2).reshape(T, F * B))

    def test_transpose_and_reshape(self):
        result = reshape(A, 'T,B,F->F,B*T')
        tc.assert_equal(result.shape, (F, B*T))
        tc.assert_equal(result, A.transpose(2, 1, 0).reshape(F, B*T))

    def test_all_comma(self):
        tc.assert_equal(reshape(A, 'T,B,F->F,1,B*T').shape, (F, 1, B*T))

    def test_all_space(self):
        tc.assert_equal(reshape(A, 't b f -> f1b*t').shape, (F, 1, B*T))


suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestReshape)
_ = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=1,stream=sys.stderr).run(suite)
```

If you prefer reading it as a gist: [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/LukasDrude/26d143a87ce6fb8b1c5c1c1297fef75f)

Comment: A while back I contributed a patch that fixed the handling of ellipsis in `np.einsum`. In course of writing that I reverse engineered `einsum`, focusing on the part the decode the index string. The code is available on my `github` at https://github.com/hpaulj/numpy-einsum/blob/master/einsum_py.py I haven't examined your code yet. I don't know if this question fits code-review or not. There aren't a lot of `numpy` eyes here (compared to StackOverflow). But you might get good general Python comments. An alternative might be a `numpy` developer's forum.

Comment: @hpaulj I am currently working through the code. I did not expect it to be that long. Once I am through, I will reconsider my code and may think about cross-posting it to a NumPy dev forum.